# How to select MM from a date

Tags: sql-server

I have a date `20190412` in this I want to pick month and year.

Below is the code I am using to get year and month

```
Select CAST(YEAR(@datecolumn) as varchar(10))+CAST(month(@datecolumn) as varchar(10)) as d
```

In the above code I am able to get year that is 2019 but I want 04 but above code give me only 4.

Can any one tell me how can I get 04 in sql server 2008.

I have update my code which I am using rite now date is coming from a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need convert the value to a `varchar`, prefix it with a  `'0'`, and take the 2 right most characters.

```
SELECT RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2),MONTH(datecolumn)),2);
```

Alternatively, you could convert the value to a `varchar` with a style, and then use `SUBSTRING`:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(8),datecolumn,112),5,2);
```

in this case, the style code 112 equates to the style `yyyyMMdd`; from which we can take the 2 characters from position 5 (the `MM` part).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATEPART(MONTH,datecolumn);
```

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql

Comment: What does "not working mean" @Amitesh? This works fine: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0b389982473ff519eb7a6f8ac89a9cce)

Comment: it will pick only 4 not 04

Comment: Did your datecolumn is a varchar or something? It should be datetime, date or datetime2.

Comment: @Amitesh: then you convert it to string... Months are from 1 to 12, not 01 to 12!